# Foreach inside a Form::select in Laravel 5.2 + default value

Tags: laravel-5

So basicaly I have this select:

```
<select name="models" id="models" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select a model</option>
    @foreach ($models as $model)
        <option value="{$model->id}">{$model->name}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I fetch my models like this:

```
$models = Model::all();
```

And I want to transform this into a `{!! Form::select() !!}` so this is what I did until now :

```
{!! Form::select('models',  $models)) !!}
```

and I fetch them like this:

```
$models= Model::lists('name', 'id');
```

It is almost perfect, what is missing is the default value. I How can I add that also to the options fetched from my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works for this case:

```
$models= Model::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();  

{!! Form::select('models', array('' => 'Select a model') + $models) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a third argument, Eg,

```
{{ Form::select('number', [0, 1, 2], 2) }}
```

Ref: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field